# How to graph $f(x)$

Tags: graphing-functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions

we have these functions :

$f(x) = \sqrt{1-\lfloor x \rfloor^2}$

$g(x) = \sqrt{\lfloor x \rfloor^2 - 1}$
[image]

How we can graph these functions ? (without using computation!)

Please Help Me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $f(x)=1, \text{  if  }0\le x <1$ and $f(x)=0, \text{  if  }1\le x < 2 \text{  or } -1 \le x <0.$ For other $x$ values you will have complex roots.

IMO you **cannot** graph $g(x)$ without computing, because there will be function values $\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{8}$ etc.

Comment: It seems in plot of $g(x)$ we have a pattern .

Comment: And distance between steps are equal.

Comment: *And distance between steps are equal:*  The step function jumps at integers, but the jumps are **not** of the same heights, even though they approach $1$ from above.